# How to display float Bokeh labels to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have Bokeh line and circle chart with pandas data source, My problem is the labels are showing up with 3 decimal places, I want to limit the values to two decimal places. please support

```
f_labels = LabelSet(x='day',
    y='Sub_Child_Incident_id',
    text='Sub_Child_Incident_id',
    level='glyph',
    x_offset=5,
    y_offset=10,
    text_font_size = "10pt",
    text_color = 'grey',
    source=source,
)
```

Comment: Did you try .round(2) on your pandas df?

Comment: It did the job many thanks dear